# Camera Rotation

Tags: animation, game-engine, camera

I'm making a game where the player clicks and it drops a cube that builds up the tower.  I want the camera to rotate slowly around the tower and move up smoothly whenever one of the blocks is dropped (I already have the logic bricking for knowing when a block is dropped).  If I could get any suggestions on how to accomplish this effect, that would be great!

Comment: What about using an action actuator?

Comment: If worst comes to worst, that's what I'm going to do.

Comment: Whats bad about an action actuator?

Comment: I was just hoping to stay away from hundreds of keyframes.

Comment: You should only need two keyframes.. Adding an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using an *Action Actuator*:

1. Add an empty
2. On frame one insert a keyframe for the Z location of the empty (<kbd>I</kbd>)
3. Move the empty up on the Z, then insert a keyframe on a later frame (I used frame 10).
4. Add some logic bricks to the empty:

   [image]

   For the action actuator select the action you created by inserting the keyframes earlier (it will be named something like `EmptyAction` by default). Don't forget to set the *end frame* to the frame on which you inserted the last keyframe.

   I used a *Motion* actuator to make it rotate continuously.
5. Parent the camera to the empty (Press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> with both objects selected and the empty active).

## Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sweet!  This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.